# Getting current action name from partial page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using a custom HtmlHelper in a partial page.

Example:

```
/Home/Index - Is the Main Page with Index View

/Home/Partial - Is the Partial Action with Partial - A Partial View
```

In the Index view:

```
Html.RenderAction("Partial");
```

In the Partial View:

I'm using a custom htmlhelper in the that htmlhelper I need to get the url of where the request is from?

Let Say It should be like "/Home/Partial"

How can I get this in my htmlhelper method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this depending on what you want. Your HtmlHelper's **ViewContext** property will have just about everything you need about the particular request: HttpContext, RequestContext, RouteData, TempData, ViewData, etc.

To get the current path of the request, try `helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path`. This would return the actual request path, likely "/" or "/home/index" if the path was explicit in the URL.

I'm not sure why you looking to get "/home/partial". Since this is a partial view the request would always come from somewhere else, eg. "/home/index".

Regardless, you can check the **RouteData** and obtain the (partial) action and controller, among other route values:

```
public static string TestHelper(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var controller = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var action = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    return controller + "/" + action;
}
```

If called in your Index view (Index.aspx) it would return "**Home/Index**".
If called in your Partial view (Partial.aspx) it would return "**Home/Partial**".

Hope that helps.